# Numpy: convert last axis to list

Tags: python, list, numpy

Let numpy array be shape (x, y, z).
I want it to be (x, y) shape with every element being a list of z-length: `[a, b, c, ..., z]`
Is there any way to do it with numpy methods?

Comment: You're looking for `x * y` number of lists, each with shape `z`? Or `z` number of lists with each element having shape `(x, y)`? Both doable, but note that performance will degrade substantially compared to simply using the original 3D array.

Comment: Please share your sample array with expected output.

Comment: why do you need a list inside a numpy array?

Comment: It would have to be an object dtype array.  Do you realize that calculations will be slower with that dtype, and some will be impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tolist` and assign to a preallocated object array:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(0,10,(100,100,100))

def f():
    A = np.empty(a.shape[:-1],object)
    A[...] = a.tolist()
    return A

f()[99,99]
# [4, 5, 9, 2, 8, 9, 9, 6, 8, 5, 7, 9, 8, 7, 6, 1, 9, 6, 2, 9, 0, 7, 0, 1, 2, 8, 4, 4, 7, 0, 1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 6, 0, 1, 4, 7, 0, 7, 9, 3, 9, 1, 8, 7, 1, 2, 3, 6, 6, 2, 7, 0, 2, 8, 7, 0, 0, 1, 8, 2, 6, 3, 5, 4, 9, 6, 9, 0, 2, 5, 9, 5, 3, 7, 0, 1, 9, 0, 8, 2, 0, 7, 3, 6, 9, 9, 4, 4, 3, 8, 4, 7, 4, 2, 1, 8]
type(f()[99,99])
# <class 'list'>

from timeit import timeit
timeit(f,number=100)*10
# 28.67872992530465
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine why numpy would need such a method. Here is, more or less, a pythonic solution.

```
import numpy as np
# an example array with shape [2,3,4] 
a = np.random.random([2,3,4])

# create the target array shaped [2,3] with 'object' type (accepting other types than numbers).
b = np.array([[None for row in mat] for mat in a])
for i in range(b.shape[0]):
   for j in range(b.shape[1]):
      b[i,j] = list(a[i,j])
```

Comment: `b = np.empty(a.shape[:2], dtype=object)`